# Solving linear system of equations with computer algebra system

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I would like to solve following system of linear equations, i.e. finding a solution $(x_{11},x_{21},x_{13},x_{23})$ for

$$
\begin{aligned}
 -(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)c_1+\alpha_8c_3
&=(\alpha_1c_1+\alpha_2c_1+\alpha_6) x_{11} +(\alpha_7- \alpha_1c_1)x_{21}\\
 \alpha_3
&=(\alpha_6-\alpha_3-\alpha_4)x_{11}+(\alpha_3+\alpha_4+\alpha_5+\alpha_7)x_{21}\\
 -\alpha_8c_3-\alpha_6
&=(\alpha_6+\alpha_1c_1+\alpha_2c_1) x_{13} +(\alpha_7- \alpha_1c_1)x_{23}\\
 -\alpha_6
&=(\alpha_6-\alpha_3-\alpha_4)x_{13}+(\alpha_3+\alpha_4+\alpha_5+\alpha_7)x_{23}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

However, it is quite tedious. Are there any good computer algebra systems, which can do this for me? How would I have to program this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In order to program that you have to know how to solve it...have you heard of matrices, Gauss operations and etc.?

Comment: It seems not so diffucult obtain $x_{11}$ and $x_{21}$ form the first two equations and $x_{13}$ and $x_{23}$ from the last two.

Comment: You can try Julia's Symbolics.jl package: https://github.com/JuliaSymbolics/Symbolics.jl . Seems easy to use.

Comment: Just write the long-winded terms using abbreviations like $P=a_1+a_2$, $Q=a_3-a_4$ and so on, then the problem becomes relatively simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend the (still free) sage, available at [link](https://www.sagemath.org).

(Sorry, I guess this should be a comment, but I still don't have the reputation to comment.)

Comment: Thank you! You are right, I was able solving it with SageMath. I used https://cocalc.com/, which is a free online environment for many programming languages, including SageMath.